# Splitting a composite variable into two variables

Tags: variables, split, stata, generate

I have a `string` variable called `country` with a value which can be for example `Afghanistan2008`, but it can also be `Brasil2012`. I would like to create two new variables, one being the country part and one the year part .

Because there are always numbers at the end of the `string`, I do know the position the `string` should be split at from the right side but not from the left side.

Could I use something like:

```
gen(substr("country",-4,.))
```

If not, could anyone tell me how to split an entire column of such variables into a `country` and a `year` variable? I would also like to keep the original variable.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a *regular expression*:

```
clear
set obs 2

generate string = ""
replace string = "Afghanistan2008" in 1
replace string = "Brasil2012" in 2

generate country = regexs(0) if regex(string, "[a-zA-Z]+")
generate year = regexs(1) + regexs(2) if regex(string, "(19|20)([0-9][0-9])")

list

   +--------------------------------------+
   |          string       country   year |
   |--------------------------------------|
1. | Afghanistan2008   Afghanistan   2008 |
2. |      Brasil2012        Brasil   2012 |
   +--------------------------------------+
```

Type `help regex` in Stata's command prompt for more information.

Alternatively you could do the following:

```
generate len = length(string) - 3

generate country2 = substr(string, 1, len - 1)
generate year2 = substr(string, len, .)

list country2 year2

   +---------------------+
   |    country2   year2 |
   |---------------------|
1. | Afghanistan    2008 |
2. |      Brasil    2012 |
   +---------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is there no way to tell the substr() function to substract the negative of 
'gen spyear = real(substr(country,-4,.))' ?

Comment: I am a little bit confused about the use of the first part of your explanation.Could I not simply use the last two lines of your explanation? 

generate country = regexs(0) if regex(string, "[a-zA-Z]+")
generate year = regexs(1) + regexs(2) if regex(string, "(19|20)([0-9][0-9])")

I am not really sure what the rest does..

Comment: Yes. The rest just creates a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (which you should had provided). I have also updated my answer to include an alternative solution based on the `substr()` function.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. 
I ended up using . "generate len = length(country) - 3
. generate spcountry = substr(country, 1, len - 1)" . Thank you for your help. Please do understand that for various reasons people sometimes just need a quick fix..

Comment: Helpful, but you don't _need_ to use a regular expression.

Comment: Strictly speaking no, a regular expression is not _needed_. However, it is a more general approach, which can be very flexible.

Comment: Your regular expression can't catch accents or spaces in names, I think.

Comment: No, but can be modified to do so, unlike the `substr()` solution. And that was my point i suppose.

Comment: Not so. I am not against regular expressions in any sense -- that would be absurd and I've written positively about them --  but my point in turn is that the `substr()` expression doesn't need modification for that case. It is sufficient to know that the last four characters give the year, and then what precedes those is the country name. What's inside the country name is immaterial.

Comment: Yes i agree but this is a simple use case. If the string is more complex or inconsistent, `substr()` will not be up to the task. My goal was to show to the OP that there is also a solution that generalizes to other more complex use cases.

Comment: Sure, we can agree that regular expressions really are needed in other problems. The OP was aware of `substr()` and close to an satisfactory, indeed excellent, solution for the problem stated. It's a close call. On Statalist I've often seen people struggle with regular expressions when something much simpler will work fine.  Experienced programmers who are comfortable with regular expressions often underestimate that. At the same time, you don't get comfortable with regular expressions unless you use them a lot.

Answer (score 1):

For my specific situation the following makes a new `year` variable:

```
gen spyear = real(substr(country,-4,.))
```

I took the other part from @PearlySpencer:

```
generate len = length(country) - 3
generate spcountry = substr(country, 1, len - 1)
```

which creates an excess column to be removed.

EDIT (Nick Cox) This can be simplified to

```
gen spyear = real(substr(country, -4, 4)) 
gen spcountry = substr(country, 1, length(country) - 4)
```

showing that

1. There is no need to create a variable containing the string length.
2. The puzzling split 4 = 3 + 1 is not needed either.